# How to replace NAs in a data-frame with the average of the nearest two available values?

Tags: r

[the link of the data with NAs](http://%20data.csv)[the link of the data with NAs](https://data.csv) I have a data-frame that contains NAs. I want to replace each NA with the average of the nearest two available values at each column. My problem is when I have more than one NA in row.

This is my data frame (data):

```
Seq Speed   Volume
1   50        8
2   70       NA
3   65       10
4   55       15
5   NA       12
6   40        9
7   NA        NA
8   NA        NA
9   NA        NA
10  30        18
11  25        NA
12  NA        22
13  NA         7
14  20         9




    for(i in data$Speed){
      data$Speed[which(is.na(data$Speed))] <- ((i+1)+(i-1))/2
    }
```

Here is what I expect to get:

```
Seq Speed   Volume
1   50        8
2   70        9
3   65       10
4   55       15
5   47.5     12
6   40       9
7   37.5     11.25
8   35       13.5
9   32.5    15.75
10  30        18
11  25        20
12  22.5      22
13  21.25     7
14  20        9
```

Comment: What you will replace the NA's with, depends on your own preference. Do you want the sequence `1,NA,NA,NA,5` to be replaced with `1,3,3,3,5`. Or something else, such as `1,2,3,4,5`?. In addition, the example code you provide will not work, because you are taking the avergae of `i+1` and `i-1`, not the values that correspond to the *index* of `i-i` and `i+1`.

Comment: Please don't add data frames as pictures. Keep this format. Thanks

Comment: @Sotos I know it will sound weird but, I don't know how to get the values from the data input above to my R session to solve the problem above. Can you help me about this? Is that readable with `read.table()` or something else?

Comment: Try package zoo. `na.approx(ddd$Volume)`

Comment: @maydin It is supposed to be [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269), but in this format, yes, you need `read.table(text = '...')`

Comment: @Sotos Thank you...I was trying without putting the `text = ` inside it!

Comment: Thanks! MKBakker and Sotos.

Comment: I want the average of the values from the nearest two (above and under) values. sometimes it happens that I have 3 NAs in row and that makes troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- tibble(
  a=c(1,3,5,NA,9),
  b=c(1,NA,NA,NA,13),
)

df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     3    NA
#> 3     5    NA
#> 4    NA    NA
#> 5     9    13

df %>%
  mutate_all(function(x){
    approx(x,n=length(x))$y
  })
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     3     4
#> 3     5     7
#> 4     7    10
#> 5     9    13
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I am getting error while applying the code! (Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Time` is of unsupported type NULL)